# mui-datatable: Get row data from onRowsDelete

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I have an mui-datatable with user data. When a row is selected and then Delete is clicked, I would like a function to also be called that deletes the object displayed in the row from the database as well. How can I access the object from the row? I only get the following array back so far.

```
data: Array(1)
  0:
    dataIndex: 0
    index: 0
  length: 1
```

**Code**

```
const options: MUIDataTableOptions = {
    onRowsDelete: (e) => deleteSelectedUser(e)
}


async function deleteSelectedUser(e: any) {
    await deleteUser().then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
}

return (
    <div>
        {
            users.length > 0 &&
                <MUIDataTable
                title={"Employee List"}
                data={users}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
                />
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of the deleted row is in `e`, try console log it.

```
async function deleteSelectedUser(e: any) {
    console.log(e); // <===================== ADD THIS LINE TO DEBUG
    await deleteUser().then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
}
```

You need to use the `dataIndex` to find the corresponding object for the delete event

Comment: Hi, when I log it, this is the output: {
    "lookup": {
        "0": true
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "dataIndex": 0
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @mapof yes, dataIndex is the index of the users array.